# Понятие контекста в веб приложении

Tags: java, java-ee

Хотел узнать что такое контекст?

1. Контекст сервлета
2. Контекст запроса

Из прочитанного мною в сети не могу понять что подразумевается под понятием контекста?  Если кто-то сможет дать линк на инфу с объяснением что такое контекст для веб приложения или дать хороший пример, я буду рад.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Понятие контекста, в широком смысле, обычно означает окружение объекта. Например, если есть некий объект, то в процессе работы приложения он будет взаимодействовать с другими объектами, иметь доступ к параметрам конфигурации, переменным, зависеть от состояния других объектов или существовать в рамках жизненного цикла. Глобальные и локальные переменные, переменные окружения, взаимодействующие с данным объекты, их состояние и т.д и т.п - все вместе образует контекст объекта - то окружение с которым он работает. Т.е. контекст - это execution / runtime окружение объекта в целом.

`ServletContext` - это объект, который содержит конфигурацию вашего приложения.
Это также интерфейс между сервлетом и контейнером сервлетов. `ServletContext` создает на старте web приложения, позволяет сервлетам и JSP получать доступ к параметрам конфигурации, описанным в web.xml, а также обмениваться данными внутри приложения.

> Defines a set of methods that a servlet uses to communicate with its
>   servlet container, for example, to get the MIME type of a file,
>   dispatch requests, or write to a log file. There is one context per
>   "web application" per Java Virtual Machine.

В Spring, аналогичный по смыслу, но более объемный по возможностям, объект называется `ApplicationContext`, что более конкретно в определении выполняемых им функций.

Аналогично, контекста запроса - это совокупность параметров и среды исполнения, которые доступны для данного запроса. Например, относящиеся только к запросу аттрибуты и HTTP заголовки.

Контекст web приложения - это по сути само web приложение в runtime.

Comment: Спасибо! Отличное объяснение..