# Суть ServletContext

Tags: java, servlet

Разбираюсь с ServletContext , саму суть я понял, с помощью этого интерфейса мы можем получить данные об окружающей среде в котором выполняется сервлет, но как эти данные применять и где на практике, не понимаю, кто может объяснить доступно

Comment: Разве не дубликат? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538462/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8

Answer (score 3):

ServletContext - это ресурс, который доступен в пределах сессии или в объекте HttpSession, который можно получить из HttpServletRequest, который доступен во всех классах участвующих в обработке http запросов, соответственно ServletContext принято использовать как session scope ресурс в контроллере или представлении стандартных MVC приложений.

И еще... Общий ресурс служит для обмена данными между самостоятельными компонентами приложения, как например переменные области видимости класса, в частных случаях служат для обмена данными между методами класса.

Comment: С чего Вы взяли, что ServletContext можно использовать как Session Scope ресурс?